# react-native FBSDK LoginManager not working

Tags: ios, react-native, fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit, react-native-fbsdk

My LoginButton works but my LoginManager doesn't.

```
handleLogin = () => {
 LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile']).then(
  function(result) {
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      alert('Login cancelled');
    } else {
      alert('Login success with permissions: '
      + result.grantedPermissions.toString());
    }
  },
  function(error) {
    alert('Login fail with error: ' + error);
  }
 )
}
```

When handleLogin() is called, it directs me to xcode showing this.

> /**
>    * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
>    * All rights reserved.
>    *
>    * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
>    * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
>    * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
>    */
>
> ## import
>
> ## import "AppDelegate.h"
>
> int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
>   @autoreleasepool {
>   return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate  > class]));
>     }
>   }

In my xcode console, the error shows this,

`2016-07-14 17:04:36.591 asklegit[2749:839107] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110e5cd85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010fd1bdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110d45934 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 164
    3   asklegit                            0x000000010f344640 -[RCTBatchedBridge _handleRequestNumber:moduleID:methodID:params:] + 368
    4   asklegit                            0x000000010f343600 __33-[RCTBatchedBridge handleBuffer:]_block_invoke.460 + 1424
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114637d9d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001146583eb _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001146401ef _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110db60f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110d77b99 __CFRunLoopRun + 2073
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110d770f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000115d0ead2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000112fb8f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    13  asklegit                            0x000000010f2c7cff main + 111
    14  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011468c92d start + 1
    15  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Anyone have an idea por favor?

Comment: I am stuck with the same problem. My only "hint" is that it probably has something to do with the way the SDK was added to the XCode project. I am looking into it today and tomorrow, any progress on your side ?

Comment: @IanBussieres Hey man, i actually solved this by deleting any references to previously used facebook login packages or files. I was using FBLoginManager from react-native-facebook-login before and i removed it from xcode and the FBSDK LoginManager works!

Comment: You should set this as the answer. I realized my colleague has installed that exact same package and its binaries. I removed everything, installed react-native-fbsdk from scratch and it works. I'll upvote your answer for sure.

Comment: @IanBussieres for sure man, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by deleting any references to previously used facebook login packages or files. I was using FBLoginManager from react-native-facebook-login before and i removed it from xcode and the FBSDK LoginManager works!

Answer (score 1):

If someone is facing this issue in **iOS**, just be careful if you are using universal Deeplinks in your application. I was using them in the application and had follow in the my application's `AppDelegate.m`.

```
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
      openURL:url
      sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
      annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];

  if ([RCTLinkingManager application:application
                                openURL:url
                      sourceApplication:nil
                             annotation:nil]{
      return YES;
   }
```

Now since deeplinking code is coming before Facebook link it takes in your url and promise never gets resolved. Thus move Linking code down to the end. So your entire code would look something like:-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
  if ( [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                                     sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                  annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]] ) {
    return YES;
  }

  if ([[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
      openURL:url
      sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
      annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]]) {
    return YES;
  }

  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                                openURL:url
                      sourceApplication:nil
                             annotation:nil];
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I found this information is explained in https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/README.md#32-ios-project . The reason is that AppDelegate.m could handle only 1 openUrl.

Comment: Yup even i saw this, guess they added it to the documentation recently